# How send class objects child form to parent form c#

Tags: c#

I want send class objects from child form to parent form. Please help me with example.Thanks !

ChildForm:

```
   List<Person> person = new List<Person>();
        private void btnGonder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendItems();
            this.Close();

        }
        public int SendItems()
        {
            Person pr = new Person();
            pr.telebe = tbTelebe.ToString();
            string telebe = tbTelebe.ToString();
            person.Add(pr);
            Form1 parent = new Form1();
            parent.SendToParent(telebe);
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: After SendItems(); nothing parent form person class

Comment: no, no... although your variable name is `parent`, it is not the `Parent` of the `child form`. Where do you instantiate the parent form?

Comment: What is the error?If you are sending an object the method header should contains the parameter you are passing.

Comment: When you do Form1 parent = new Form1 you are creating a new parent form it is not the form that created your child form. Either pass the parent form in your child forms constructor or if you are using Show or ShowDialog use the overload that assigns the owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

ChildForm:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    // private List of Person(s)
    private List<Person> PersonsList = new List<Person>();

    // Public Read-only property that you can call from you Parent Form
    public List<Person> Frm2PersonsList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.PersonsList;
        }
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGonder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendItems();
        this.Close();
    }

    public void SendItems()
    {
        Person pr = new Person();
        pr.telebe = "Set in form 2"; // set you Person properties here
        PersonsList.Add(pr);
    }
}
```

ParentForm:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.ShowDialog();
        List<Person> Frm1PersonsList = frm2.Frm2PersonsList; // set a breakpoint here and step though the code to see the result from the Child Form
    }
}
```